# How to use multiple for in template to get elements from object in django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-templates, jinja2

I am passing below variables from backend. I want to get values dynamically.

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
answers = [
{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 26), 1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None},
 {'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 27), 1: 100.0, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}
]
```

In my template I used:

```
{% for i in answers %}
  <tr>
     <td>{{i.date}}</td>
     {% for j in num_list %}
        <td>{{i.j}}</td>
     {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Using the above code in templates is not giving me the output, it just displays empty.
but if type manually it works.

```
<td>{{i.1}}</td>
<td>{{i.2}}</td>
.
.
<td>{{i.9}}</td>
```

Any Solution to solve this?

Comment: Try writing the following code out in python. Where does it go wrong? You cannot use a variable to access a method on a class like this. You need to use the method. Same principle.

Comment: @nigel239 I want to create dynamic table where I don't know how many row and columns in a table will be. Based on selected subject it will give me columns and row. If I try that in python it'll obviously work, but I want that in template using jinja.

Comment: Maybe this will help you if it's based on a model. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73454813/18020941 The above doesn't work, because `{{j}}` is not an attribute of `{{i}}`, so you cannot do `{{i.j}}` An alternative would be to pack it into another list: `{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 26), "num_list":[100.0, 50.0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],}`, then you can call: `{% for j in i.num_list %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pack the answers into a separate list, like so:

```
{'date': datetime.date(2022, 8, 26), "num_list":[100.0, 50.0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],}
```

Then in the template, you can easily access the list with:

```
{% for i in answers %}
...
    {% for j in i.num_list %}
    ....
```

The above doesn't work, because `{{j}}` is not an attribute of `{{i}}`, so you cannot do `{{i.j}}`